# read docx file from a server on a WKWebView

Tags: php, swift, docx

**How can I show a .docx file generate on a PHP server on a view with web view?**

If I change the url to https://www.google.ca/, it is shown on the view, but when I try to read http://blog.local:4711/api/invoices/69/download it shows a blank area.

On console using breakpoints, I see it going to the correct line.

By using the same url (http://blog.local:4711/api/invoices/69/download) on any browser, I get to download the file.

swift code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class InvoicePreviewViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var preview: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        let url = URL(string: "http://blog.local:4711/api/invoices/69/download")

        if let unwrappedURL = url {
            let request = URLRequest(url: unwrappedURL)
            let session = URLSession.shared

            let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
                if error == nil {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                        self.preview.load(request)
                    }
                } else {
                    print("no")
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }

}
```

PHP code

```
 ...
        $filename = $this->filename;        
        $this->_templateProcessor->saveAs($filename);
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
        flush();
        readfile($filename);
        unlink($filename); // deletes the temporary file
        exit;
```

Comment: You're sending a mime type of `application/octet-stream` and a `Content-Disposition` of `attachment`. Try removing the content disposition and setting the mime type to the actual DOCX mime type (`application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`).

Comment: thank you.... it is still blank.... and on browser it shows a different save dialog box

Answer (score 0):

Following what John Ellmore answered it worked..... BUT, I dont know why..... only after I restart Xcode.